# Múltiples criterios en búsqueda AJAX en mySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas!!

Tengo un script para buscar en mySQL con php y ajax que funciona correctamente con 1 campo input. En el index.php tengo el formulario y el script y en el archivo fetch.php tengo el código de búsqueda.

Ahora necesito poner otro campo de búsqueda tipo dropdown. El script tendrá que coger los valores de ambos campos, enviárselos al archivo fetch.php con el método POST y éste deberá leerlos para poder hacer la búsqueda.

¿Podríais echarme un cable?
Gracias!

Archivo **index.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>DEMO</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">TITULO DEMO</h2><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group" style="display:initial!important">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">¿Qué canción estás buscando?</span>
                    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Escribe el título, autor o género" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Archivo **fetch.php**:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "nombre_db");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM NOMBRE_TABLA 
    WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR 'ano' LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR 'disco' LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR 'duracion' LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ORDER BY nombre ASC
    ";
}
else
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM NOMBRE_TABLA ORDER BY nombre ASC";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table bordered table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Canción</th>
                            <th>Año</th>
                            <th>Disco</th>
                            <th>Duración</th>
                        </tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["ano"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["disco"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["duracion"].'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo $output;
}
else
{
    echo '¡No encontramos ninguna canción!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta (o tu código)  no son claros. ¿Dónde está el dropdown del que hablas?  ¿Por qué lanzas la petición Ajax usando `keyup`?, acaso irás a buscar cada vez que se deje de presionar una tecla... no eso lo que dices al plantear la pregunta. ¿Quizá quieres escribir un dato en el ´input`, seleccionar otra cosa en el dropdown y luego lanzar la búsqueda con esos dos valores?

Comment: Buenas y gracias por tu respuesta. El código que he puesto es el que tengo funcionando. Necesito ayuda para añadir la funcionalidad que necesito.
Como comentaba, lo que necesito es añadir un dropdown en el index.php y que esta nueva variable se pase también mediante POST al fetch.php para que éste pueda hacer búsquedas en mySQL por esos dos cambios, en lugar de hacerlo sólo por 1 como lo hace ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo esta solución, centrándonos únicamente en lo que pides en la pregunta.

El ejemplo muestra cómo enviar al servidor el nombre de una persona y el valor identificador de una ciudad que se guarda en un `select`.

El código que propongo tiene las siguientes ventajas:

- Usa elementos actualizados de jQuery, tales como `function`, `done`, `fail` ... tu código usaba elementos obsoletos en ese sentido.
- Yo trabajo con variables, me parece que el código queda más claro
- Notarás que el botón `Enviar` aparece en principio desactivado. No se activará hasta que no se cumplan dos condiciones: que el input no esté vacío y que en el  select se seleccione una opción válida. Con esto evitamos que desde el cliente se envíen peticiones absurdas al servidor.
- En la petición Ajax yo leo los atributos del formulario para determinar la url y el método
- He puesto también un div para informar en pantalla de lo que pase en el servidor (esto es opcional).

```js
$(function() {
  /*Elementos del DOM*/
  var $inputName = $("#name");
  var $selectCity = $("#city");
  var $btnSend = $("#btnEnviar");

  /*Valores*/
  var valName = "";
  var valCity = "";
  var btnStatus = false;

  /*Listeners*/
  $selectCity.on('change', myListener);
  $inputName.keyup(myListener);
  $btnSend.on('click', postAjax);

  /*Función que escucha los cambios*/
  function myListener() {
    valName = $.trim($("#name").val());
    valCity = parseInt($selectCity.val());
    /*
     *Verificamos si se puede activar el botón
     */
    btnStatus = (valName && valCity > 0) ? false : true;
    $btnSend.prop('disabled', btnStatus);
  }

  /*Función que envía los datos al servidor al hacer clic en Enviar*/
  function postAjax() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $frm = $("#frmFetch");
    var postData = {
      name: valName,
      city: valCity
    };
    var postUrl = $frm.attr("action");
    var postMethod = $frm.attr("method");
    console.log(`Se enviará al servidor: `);
    console.log(postData);


    /*
       *He comentado la petición Ajax para que no de error
       *en stackoveflow, descomenta este bloque en tu servidor
*----------------------------------------------------------------
       
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: postUrl,
      method: postMethod,
      data: postData,
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      $("#info").html(msg);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });

*----------------------------------------------------------------
*/
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmFetch" action="fetch.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="post_name" placeholder="Escribe un nombre" required>
  <label for="city">Ciudad:</label>
  <select id="city" name="post_city">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">-Seleccione una ciudad-</option>
    <option value="1">Madrid</option>
    <option value="1">New York</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btnEnviar" disabled>Enviar</button>
</form>
<div id="info"></div>
```

---

### PHP

El código enviará dos valores al servidor.

Yo los capturaría así:

```
$name=(!empty($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : NULL;
$city=(!empty($_POST["city"]) ? $_POST["city"] : NULL;
if ($name && $city){
    //Lanzamos la consulta
    //Cuando haga falta usaremos $name y $city
}
```

---

> #### P.S.
>
> No quiero meterme con tu código PHP, pero quiero dejar aquí una nota
>   de que el mismo es actualmente altamente vulnerable a ataques de
>   inyección SQL. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para corregir
>   ese grave agujero de seguridad.